# vhdl std_logic not declared error

Tags: vhdl

I'm keep getting this annoying error that the std_logic is not declared. I don't know why am I getting this error because I have included all necessary libraries.
here's my code and the errors.

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------
          -- Company: 
          -- Engineer: 
          -- 
-- Create Date:    15:26:41 08/23/2015 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    Deficit-Round_Robbin_algorithem - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
package TwoDArray is
  Type array_integer is array(1 to 6) of integer range 0 to 6;
end package TwoDArray;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

  entity Deficit_Round_Robbin_algorithem is

generic(
Quantom:integer range 0 to 256:=2;
Num_queues:integer:=5 ;
IN_FIFO_DEPTH_BIT:integer:=6
);
port(
clk,axi_resetn,m_axis_tready:in std_logic;
--packet_size:in array_integer range 0 to Num_queues+1;
--fifo_out_tlast,empty:in std_logic_vector(Num_queues - 1 downto 0);
--depth_of_fifo:in integer range 0 to Num_queues+1;
--rd_en:out std_logic_vector(Num_queues - 1 downto 0);
pkt_fwd:out std_logic
);
end Deficit_Round_Robbin_algorithem;

architecture Behavioral of Deficit_Round_Robbin_algorithem is
--signal cur_queue,cur_queue_next,cur_queue_plus1:integer range 0 to Num_queues-1:=0;
--signal pkt_fwd_next:std_logic:='0'; 
--
--signal Drr_counter:array_integer ;
--
--subType STATE_TYPE is bit_vector (1 downto 0);
--signal next_state,state:STATE_TYPE :="00"; --00 start state
--constant Idle:STATE_TYPE:="00";
--constant WR_PKT:STATE_TYPE:="01";
begin
--cur_queue_plus1<=0 when cur_queue=Num_queues-1 else cur_queue + 1;
--Drr_counter[cur_queue]<=Drr_counter[cur_queue] + Quantom;
--Medvedev_state_diagram:process(state,cur_queue,empty,m_axis_tready,fifo_out_tlast,depth_of_fifo) is
--begin
--      cur_queue_next  <= cur_queue;
--      rd_en           <= (others =>'0');
--      pkt_fwd_next    <= '0';
--      case state is
--      when Idle=> if(empty[cur_queue]='0') then
--                          if(m_axis_tready) then
--                              if(Drr_counter[cur_queue] >= packet_size[cur_queue]) then
--                                  next_state<= WR_PKT;
--                                  rd_en[cur_queue] <= '1';
--                                  pkt_fwd_next <= '1';
--                              end if;
--                          end if;
--                      else
--                      cur_queue_next <= cur_queue_plus1;
--                      end if;
--                      end case;
--end process;

end Behavioral;
```

My errors

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "I:\xilinx\Deficit-Round_Rrobbin\Deficit-Round_Robbin_algorithem.vhd" Line 42: <std_logic> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "I:\xilinx\Deficit-Round_Rrobbin\Deficit-Round_Robbin_algorithem.vhd" Line 47: <std_logic> is not declared.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "I:\xilinx\Deficit-Round_Rrobbin\Deficit-Round_Robbin_algorithem.vhd" Line 34: Unit <deficit_round_robbin_algorithem> ignored due to previous errors.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:374 - "I:\xilinx\Deficit-Round_Rrobbin\Deficit-Round_Robbin_algorithem.vhd" Line 51: Entity <deficit_round_robbin_algorithem> is not yet compiled.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use clauses (library declarations) are actually part of library unit declarations (package, entity, configuration, etc) in VHDL. They do not apply globally to all library units declared in a file.

So in your case, the use clause to import the IEEE libraries at the top of your file are only applied to the package `TwoDArray`. You'll need to redefine the libraries that apply to `Deficit_Round_Robbin_algorithem` after the package declaration.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
package TwoDArray is
  Type array_integer is array(1 to 6) of integer range 0 to 6;
end package TwoDArray;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library work;
use work.TwoDArray.all;

entity Deficit_Round_Robbin_algorithem is
generic(
...
```

Edit: Added `TwoDArray` package to entity's use clause as per comments.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.4 Context clauses, "A context clause defines the initial name environment in which a design unit is analyzed." "A library clause defines library logical names that may be referenced in the design unit; library clauses are described in 13.2. A use clause makes certain declarations directly visible within the design unit; use clauses are described in 12.4." 13.2 "Every design unit except a context declaration and package STANDARD is assumed to contain the following implicit context items as part of its context clause:
library STD, WORK; use STD.STANDARD.all;" No std_logic.

Comment: wow what a great answer. thanks a lot!!!!!! just another question how can a use the package that I have created.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add `TwoDArray` to  `Deficit_Round_Robbin_algorithem`'s use clause. This assumes however that you are compiling this file to the default library `work`.